# Is there a way to identify the PCIE Speed for a device using powershell (Win10)?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, motherboard, pci-express

This way I can determine the transfer rate of the device and relate that to the generation of the PCIE device (PCIE 3.0, 4.0, etc)

Comment: The title is not the question. Please use the EDIT button to clarify your question, adding some context, what you've tried, research you've done, etc.

Comment: [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: The OP is asking about speeds, and there is no native way to do this with the native cmdlets, because it's not an available property. One can see this via Get-Member as per the pointer 'Reddy Lutonadio', links provided.

Comment: don't change the question significantly after it has been answered because it'll make current answers invalid. Just ask a different question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This method uses the WMI Bus PnP device driver properties

```
# Get all devices related to PCI BUS 
$pciStats = (Get-WMIObject Win32_Bus -Filter 'DeviceID like "PCI%"').GetRelated('Win32_PnPEntity') | 
  foreach {
    # request connection properties from wmi
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
      Name = $_.Name
      ExpressSpecVersion=$_.GetDeviceProperties('DEVPKEY_PciDevice_ExpressSpecVersion').deviceProperties.data
      MaxLinkSpeed      =$_.GetDeviceProperties('DEVPKEY_PciDevice_MaxLinkSpeed'      ).deviceProperties.data
      MaxLinkWidth      =$_.GetDeviceProperties('DEVPKEY_PciDevice_MaxLinkWidth'      ).deviceProperties.data
      CurrentLinkSpeed  =$_.GetDeviceProperties('DEVPKEY_PciDevice_CurrentLinkSpeed'  ).deviceProperties.data
      CurrentLinkWidth  =$_.GetDeviceProperties('DEVPKEY_PciDevice_CurrentLinkWidth'  ).deviceProperties.data
    } |
    # only keep devices with PCI connections
    Where MaxLinkSpeed
  }
$pciStats | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

It shows a table like this on my PC:

```
Name                             ExpressSpecVersion MaxLinkSpeed MaxLinkWidth CurrentLinkSpeed CurrentLinkWidth
----                             ------------------ ------------ ------------ ---------------- ----------------
High Definition Audio Controller                  2            4           16                3               16
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070                           2            4           16                3               16
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8                  2            1            1                1                1
ASMedia USB 3.1 eXtensible Host                   2            3            2                3                2
Standard NVM Express Controller                   2            3            4                3                4
```

the `ExpressSpecVersion` property is the PCIe version, where PCIe 1.0 = `0` and PCIe 3.0 = `2`, etc. The integer values for the other properties aren't too hard to find by googling their driver key name, like `DEVPKEY_PciDevice_MaxLinkSpeed`

These properties are for the named device, and **not** the PCI slot on the motherboard. WMI doesn't seem to enumerate info about the pci ports, especially not disconnected ones.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the integer values for the other properties or add a link to some kind of documentation? Googling the driver key names only brought up this Q&A, an MSDN thread and a clang header file, all of which don't explain what those numbers actually mean.

Comment: @danzel I found the MS doc with descriptions of each PciDevice property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddndis/ns-ntddndis-_ndis_pci_device_custom_properties and this MS example driver file has a description for most of the integer values, though most of it is beyond me: https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/shared/pciprop.h As a sidenote, I found Bing works much better for MS docs :shrug:

Comment: thank you for the links. Unfortunately, they don't explain the values either. For example, there is `#define DevProp_PciExpressDevice_Spec_Version_11        2`, which indicates that a value of `2` means PCIe 1.1, not 3.0...

Comment: I especially appreciate this answer for providing ExpressSpecVersion, MaxLinkSpeed, MaxLinkWidth. Thank you, @Cpt.Whale